# glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'

Tags: python, glob

I try to run a script that uses the glob() function, but it gives me this error:

```
imagePatches = glob('/kaggle/input/IDC_regular_ps50_idx5/**/*.png', recursive=True)
```

```
TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'
```

im using python2.7

Comment: Apparently this is not a Python 2.7 script. Get Python 3.

Answer (score 13):

Support for `**` and the `recursive` argument was only [added in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

The [Python 2 version of `glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) only takes a single argument.